# I want write code to predict CIE XYZ from LED driver R,G,B output value

Tags: colors, led, color-space

I am making auto white balance calibration application.
I have a chromameter and api. So my application can measure CIExyY and CIEXYZ.
And my app can set R,G,B output value of my devices's LED panel.

I set R,G,B value combination and measureed CIEXYZ three times.
And then I evaluated follow matrix.

[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhy6w.png)

I thought that once I evaluated the matrix, I could calculate CIEXYZ with R,G,B output value.

But It's not correct value.

R,G,B output value is 0~1023. 0 doesn't mean 0 output. 0~1023 is just level.

Answer (score 0):

Using [colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour), given the primaries and whitepoint expressed as CIE XYZ tristimulus, you can compute the normalised primary matrix converting from your LED colourspace to CIE XYZ as follows:

```py
import colour
import numpy as np

XYZ_PRIMARIES = np.array(
    [
        [2.12500000, 1.00000000, -0.00000000],
        [0.38405797, 1.00000000, 0.06521739],
        [2.50000000, 1.00000000, 13.16666667],
    ]
)
XYZ_WHITEPOINT = np.array([0.89458689, 1.00000000, 0.95441595])

NPM = colour.normalised_primary_matrix(
    colour.XYZ_to_xy(XYZ_PRIMARIES), colour.XYZ_to_xy(XYZ_WHITEPOINT)
)

print(NPM)
print(np.linalg.inv(NPM))
```

```
[[  4.45169812e-01   2.77134409e-01   1.72282669e-01]
 [  2.09491676e-01   7.21595256e-01   6.89130676e-02]
 [ -3.63410128e-17   4.70605593e-02   9.07355391e-01]]
[[ 2.72539405 -1.01800301 -0.4401632 ]
 [-0.79516802  1.68973205  0.02264719]
 [ 0.04124189 -0.08763902  1.10092938]]
```

You can also create a new RGB colourspace which will allow you to convert to other known colourspaces:

```py
RGB_COLOURSPACE_LED = colour.RGB_Colourspace(
    "LED", colour.XYZ_to_xy(XYZ_PRIMARIES), colour.XYZ_to_xy(XYZ_WHITEPOINT)
)
print(RGB_COLOURSPACE_LED)

print(
    colour.matrix_RGB_to_RGB(RGB_COLOURSPACE_LED, colour.models.RGB_COLOURSPACE_BT2020)
)
```

```
[[  7.05392504e-01   2.49107517e-01   4.54999792e-02]
 [  4.04429548e-02   9.47423997e-01   1.21330485e-02]
 [ -5.83382089e-04   2.69551875e-02   9.73628195e-01]]
```

Note that this assumes that the LED behave linearly which is almost certainly not the case!

Comment: I need to find RGB value of white point automatically. So I can not input white point value before running app. Instead. I can measure these values.(1023,1023,1023)=(x1,y2,z3) (1023,0,0)=(x2,y2,z2) (0,1023,0)=(x3,y3,z3) (0,0,1023)=(x4,y4,z4) Can I evaluate a matrix with these values.

Comment: The whitepoint is (1023,1023,1023)=(x1,y2,z3).

Comment: Do you mean white is (1023,1023,1023) prmaries are (1023, 0, 0), (0,1023,0), (0, 0, 1023)? So I can make my own color space with the colour library. May I need measure four times for that? Thank you for you do for me. I will try it.

Comment: Yes absolutely, when you measure each individual R, G, B and R+G+B, you have obtained the primaries and whitepoint.